# Hibernate query to search for a particular sub string in a string field

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a field in one of my tables that has a field to store `urls` and the `POJO` for that table is as follows:

```
public class ContentDefinition 
    {
        private String contentName;
        private int contentId;
        private String contentType;
        private String contentUrl;

    }
```

I am trying to write a query to check if the `contentUrl` field contains url that ends with the string `address-book`.

I am using the following query:

```
String hql = " from ContentDefinition WHERE contentUrl LIKE '%'address-book'%'";
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
List<ContentDefinition> resultsList = query.list();
```

but I am getting an exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: address near line 1, column 130
```

Is there any solution, my url can be anything, but always ends with `/address-book`

Comment: The query should be like 
" from Document doc fetch all properties where lower(doc.name) like '%cats%' " 

I think there is no need to enclose address-book in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql = " from ContentDefinition WHERE contentUrl LIKE :addressBook "; 
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("addressBook","address-book");
List<ContentDefinition> resultsList = query.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

String hql = " from ContentDefinition WHERE contentUrl LIKE '%address-book%' ";

Change above line. Rest of code looks good. I have tested a similar code.

Answer (score 1):

Read upon chapter [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

The doc says:

> The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.
>
> `where animalType like '%cats%'`

Which means, you should change your query from:

```
String hql = " from ContentDefinition WHERE contentUrl LIKE '%'address-book'%'";
```

to

```
String hql = " from ContentDefinition WHERE contentUrl LIKE '%address-book%'";
```